# ClassNotFoundException despite providing the correct Gradle dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

In a Spring Boot 3.0.4 project using Gradle 7.4.2 and JDK 17, I am facing a (vastly) documented error when running my application with `gradlew bootRun` :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
```

I am then adding this dependency :

```
 runtimeOnly group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version:'4.0.0'
```

When running `gradlew dependencies` , I get this for `runtimeClasspath` :

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 3.0.4
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.0.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.0.4
...
+--- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.3
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 (*)
+--- org.codehaus.janino:janino -> 3.1.9
|    \--- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.1.9
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations -> 2.14.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.2 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 (*)
|    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 -> 4.0.0 (*)
|    +--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2 -> 2.1.1
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.14.2 (*)
\--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.0
     \--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.0 -> 4.0.2
          +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0 (*)
          \--- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:2.0.0 (*)
```

So `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0` is present, and therefore `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement` should be found (I see it belongs to the jakarta.xml.bind-api jar in my IDE).. but it's not.

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is strange...

Originally, my dependencies were :

```
runtimeOnly group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '7.3'
runtimeOnly group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino'
```

But I was getting this error :

```
Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
```

So I added this dependency so that finds the missing class :

```
runtimeOnly group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations'
```

But then I was getting :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
```

And adding `runtimeOnly group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version:'4.0.0'` was not helping, as described in the question.

Now, **I've just removed `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` and left `jaxb-impl`, and it works**.. I am a bit puzzled on the "why" though..

Here's the output of `dependencies` task :

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 3.0.4
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.0.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.0.4
...
+--- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.3
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 (*)
+--- org.codehaus.janino:janino -> 3.1.9
|    \--- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.1.9
\--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0 (*)
```